# How to perform summary validation for the following code?

Tags: android, validation, authentication, validationsummary

[image]

```
if((noValidate.getText().toString().length()>0)  &&     (nameValidate.getText().toString().length()>0)  &&
            (conpassValidate.getText().toString() ==  passValidate.getText().toString()) &&  (email.matches(emailPattern))
            &&(passValidate.getText().toString().length()>0))
        {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Information are saved succesfully ",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent getStarted = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  FourthActivity.class);
        startActivity(getStarted);
        }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Field Requiered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}
```

here when i click on the sign in button it will validate and summerise the field. If any field is empty it will show that field required. if i entered data in all field means it always shows that field required. I don't know where was the problem.

Comment: Can you post your error log?. because error might be in your  FourthActivity.class!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you cannot compare strings using an equal operator (=):

```
conpassValidate.getText().toString() ==  passValidate.getText().toString()
```

Use the equal method instead:

```
conpassValidate.getText().toString().equals(passValidate.getText().toString())
```

This would be the full code:

```
if((noValidate.getText().toString().length()>0)  &&     
   (nameValidate.getText().toString().length()>0)  &&
   (conpassValidate.getText().toString().equals(passValidate.getText().toString())) &&  
   (email.matches(emailPattern)) && 
   (passValidate.getText().toString().length()>0)) {

       Toast.makeText(this, "Your Information are saved succesfully ",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Intent getStarted = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  FourthActivity.class);
       startActivity(getStarted);
} else {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Field Requiered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

If this still does not work, print your validation using this code after else

```
String tag = "Your Tag";
Log.d(tag, "1: " + noValidate.getText().toString().length()>0 ? "YES":"NO");
Log.d(tag, "2: " + nameValidate.getText().toString().length()>0 ? "YES":"NO");
Log.d(tag, "3: " + conpassValidate.getText().toString().equals(passValidate.getText().toString()) ? "YES":"NO");
Log.d(tag, "4: " + email.matches(emailPattern) ? "YES":"NO");
Log.d(tag, "5: " + passValidate.getText().toString().length()>0 ? "YES":"NO");
```

Comment: I'd suggest printing the validation using my added code above.

Comment: i am beginner. so kindly tell me where can i add the above code.

Comment: Between the lines `} else {` and `Toast.makeText(this, "Field Requiered"...`.